# check if file exists in project folder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, file, path, nsfilemanager

My project has this structure:

```
my_project
 my_project
  AppDelegate.m
  AppDelegate.h
  ...
  Audio_folder
   my_audio.mp3
```

So I want to check if an audio file exists or not in the `Audio_folder`.
I can do it with the full path

```
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Users/user/Desktop/my_project/my_project/Audio_folder/my_audio.mp3"];
```

but how can I achieve it with something like

```
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"Audio/my_audio.mp3"];
```

?

Comment: @"/Audio_folder/my_audio.mp3" <-- This should work no? As doing it assumes current directory, which is your project path

Comment: are you sure it will be saved there? most of the times, inside the project folder (finder) they will all be on root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to know whether this is available or not at runtime is by using [NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/).

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_audio" ofType:@"mp3"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
```

In `fileExists` you know if it is available.

Be sure to check the build-phases if the file is copied to the bundle.

Comment: it says `use of undeclared identifier pathAndFileName`

Answer (score 0):

NSFileManager has absolutely no access to the project folder. It's completely relevant to the folder in which the App lives or in which the documents it accesses lives.

The build process and the actual running of an app are divided between "developer land" and "user land"..

The only way to access the developer folder is though obtuse methods that defy the sandbox environment. Even if apple do allow a temporary exception it's highly unlikely it'll stay in play.

The only way I can recommend sharing the two is at the build stage using a Script which shares a common folder between the two...

Comment: so is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Only way as far as I know is: (i) copy the file with build (or process with script), (ii) output as whatever format you need (iii) done. Other than horribly articulated scripts to circumvent this, I haven't seen any other way to do this...